# Image and wrapped text over two columns

Tags: graphics, two-column, wrapfigure

I'm working on a longer document set for two columns. Each chapter is supposed to start with an image and text wrapping around the text - all of this set in ONE column.
Using \onecolumn \twocolumn generates blank pages that I don't want. Using multicols with a base document set to one column throws other parts of the document off (namely sets of several minipages start flowing over the margins).

The best I could hack together right now is using a page-wide minipage for the chapter start like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn, openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.4in, left=1.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part*{Paragraph Title}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{placeholder}
  \end{center}
  \caption{A gull}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\end{minipage}

\section*{Overview}
\lipsum[20-22]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, text following the minipage (here section overview) gets set "normally" and ends up running happily into the right column, smack into the text from the minipage.

How would I achieve what I try to do "correctly"?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn, openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.4in, left=1.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{cuted}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\begin{strip}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{center}
  \caption{A gull}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}
\end{strip}


\section*{Overview}
\lipsum[20-22]
\end{document}
```

Comment: My compliments for your score of 10k.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thank you very much. A year ago I would have never expected that.

Comment: I am very happy for you, sincerely. Good people always do deserve the best. A hug.